# (ClassGenException) Couldn't find target for branch: ifeq[153]

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin, spring-aspects

Aspectj version : 1.8.13

I have a project which I am trying to run through aspect compiler through maven plug-in but getting following error.

Any pointers to debug this issue or find the exact issue where it lies? . The error couldn't find the branch does not tell the line no. It justs print the opcode.

MVN

```
  <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${aspectj.maven.plugin.version}</version>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.mycomapny</groupId>
                        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <configuration>
                    <source>${JAVA_SOURCE_VERSION}</source>
                    <target>${JAVA_TARGET_VERSION}</target>
                    <complianceLevel>${JAVA_TARGET_VERSION}</complianceLevel>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                    <weaveDirectories>
                        <weaveDirectory>${project.build.directory}/unwoven-classes</weaveDirectory>
                    </weaveDirectories>
                    <sources>
                        <source/>
                    </sources>
                    <testSources>
                        <source/>
                    </testSources>
                    <forceAjcCompile>true</forceAjcCompile>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/aspects/**</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
                            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
```

```
[ERROR] com.mycompany.targetclass -- (ClassGenException) Couldn't find target for branch: ifeq[153](size3) -> null
[ERROR] Couldn't find target for branch: ifeq[153](size3) -> null
[ERROR] org.aspectj.apache.bcel.generic.ClassGenException: Couldn't find target for branch: ifeq[153](size3) -> null
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.generic.InstructionList.<init>(InstructionList.java:223)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.generic.MethodGen.<init>(MethodGen.java:212)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.LazyMethodGen.initialize(LazyMethodGen.java:372)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.LazyMethodGen.markAsChanged(LazyMethodGen.java:540)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.LazyMethodGen.getBody(LazyMethodGen.java:929)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelShadow.init(BcelShadow.java:668)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelClassWeaver.match(BcelClassWeaver.java:2693)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelClassWeaver.weave(BcelClassWeaver.java:480)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelClassWeaver.weave(BcelClassWeaver.java:100)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weave(BcelWeaver.java:1692)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weaveWithoutDump(BcelWeaver.java:1636)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weaveAndNotify(BcelWeaver.java:1401)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weave(BcelWeaver.java:1183)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.AjPipeliningCompilerAdapter.weaveQueuedEntries(AjPipeliningCompilerAdapter.java:514)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.AjPipeliningCompilerAdapter.afterCompiling(AjPipeliningCompilerAdapter.java:375)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.CompilerAdapter.ajc$afterReturning$org_aspectj_ajdt_internal_compiler_CompilerAdapter$2$f9cc9ca0(CompilerAdapter.aj:78)

Caused by: org.aspectj.apache.bcel.generic.ClassGenException: Couldn't find target for branch: ifeq[153](size3) -> null
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.generic.InstructionList.<init>(InstructionList.java:223)
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.generic.MethodGen.<init>(MethodGen.java:212)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.LazyMethodGen.initialize(LazyMethodGen.java:372)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.LazyMethodGen.getReturnType(LazyMethodGen.java:920)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.LazyMethodGen.toShortString(LazyMethodGen.java:562)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.LazyMethodGen.print(LazyMethodGen.java:603)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.LazyClassGen.printOne(LazyClassGen.java:860)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.LazyClassGen.print(LazyClassGen.java:819)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.LazyClassGen.toLongString(LazyClassGen.java:807)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weave(BcelWeaver.java:1711)
```

Comment: It is difficult to answer this kind of question the there is no [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). So please condense and simplify your project to some minimal version reproducing the problem, publish it on GitHub and share a link here. I know quite a bit about AspectJ and AspectJ Maven, so I would be willing to take a look - if I had something to look at. I need a full Maven POM, a minimal application and the aspects. BTW, I don't understand why you think you have to add your own module and spring-aspects as AspectJ Maven plugin dependencies.

Comment: HI kregaex, Thanks for kind response. The issue has been identified. Aspectj 1.8.13 does not support Lambda expressions.  My annotated code used lambda expression at some parts.  I converted lambda expressions to non-lambda constructs and compilation passes now.

Comment: Your statement that AspectJ 1.8.13 does not support lambda expressions is not true in general. Please share an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing the problem, just in case you have uncovered an error. Don't just ask questions and then leave them open. This is a community website, I suggest you try to give something back to the community that was supposed to help you and surely would have if you had share the MCVE I asked you for in the first place. It is not even clear is you use lambdas in AspectJ or in a target class, what kind of pointcuts and advices you use etc.